# How to get the Classic Start Menu in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

Classic start menu is simple and efficient, but the Vista style start menu gets in the way from letting me get on with what I want to do. It also has features I don't want, such as an irritating bitmap that changes according to where the cursor hovers. I've managed to disable most of the unwanted cosmetics and animations but it's still not the dull old Classic Menu that I prefer. How to get the Classic Start Menu in Windows 7 but without a [kludge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kludge) if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The free [Classic Shell](http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/features.html) does a classic start menu for Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

The [HowToGeek](https://superuser.com/users/4102/the-how-to-geek) has an elegant solution [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/2227/get-the-classic-start-menu-in-windows-7/) on how this can be done.

The functionality has been removed in Windows 7, most likely because of the new TaskBar among other reasons, and most people using Vista extensively have gotten used to using Search to find applications rather then navigating a huge amount of menu's.

The solution requires you to download an application called [CSMenu](http://www.csmenu.com/) which simulates the Classic Menu, and is free. To completely replace the Windows 7 Menu you will also need to download [StartKiller](http://www.tordex.com/startkiller/) which will remove the start button and allow you to use CSMenu instead.

Comment: If however you switch to the Classic Theme, I don't think you need StartKiller. Correct?

Comment: @A Dwarf I am not sure. I haven't tried it at all so I can't comment.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a bit of a kludge.

Comment: @Rob. Unfortunatly it is but there is no other way to get the classic menu in Windows 7. I checked tonight and it has definitly been removed.

Comment: Using Search to find applications works great, but it's lost when reverting to the Classic Menu.