# enabling "classic" look in Windows 7 - or at least reducing window edge widths

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, themes, system-preferences

After looking [here](https://superuser.com/q/63040/978), I'm still at a loss.

Is it possible to enable a "Classic" view *a la* Windows XP's theme that would make the environment look more like Windows 2000?

If not, is there a way to reduce the size of Window borders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, 
Open `My Computer` > Click on `System Properties` > `Advance System Settings` (At left pane) > `Advance` Tab > `Setting` (Under Performance) > Click on `Adjust for Best Performance`. Click OK a few times.

After all these there should be notable change in the visuals of the screen.

Alternatively <s>if you are on Windows 7 Ultimate (other version won't support)</s> you can simply right click on the desktop > select personalize :
Here themes are arranged into 3 sections.

- **Unsaved Theme** (If you have recently changed your wallpaper recently..)
- **Aero theme** (This is the collection that Microsoft offers with Windows)
- The last one is **Basic and High Contrast Themes**, here you will find **Windows Classic** theme that you are in need of.

Comment: Umm, Home Premium, Enterprise and Professional support the classic theme.

Comment: @surfasb And is that worth a down vote? With current edits, Santosh's answer addresses the question better than yours does. +1 from me to compensate.

Comment: I still don't see how this pertains only to WinUltimate.

Comment: @surfasb I have done some editing, how is it now?

Comment: Looks like a winner to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the border padding by going under Control Panel -> Personalization -> Advanced Settings -> Border Padding.

[image]

Comment: Since you're answering the "if not" section of the question, are you saying that it's _not_ possible to change to a "classic" look?