# How to change the theme of Windows 8 to the classic theme?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-8, themes

I would like to change the theme of my Windows 8 install to the Windows Classic theme:

[image: classic theme].

Comment: possible duplicate of [enabling "classic" look in Windows 7 - or at least reducing window edge widths](http://superuser.com/questions/404956/enabling-classic-look-in-windows-7-or-at-least-reducing-window-edge-widths)

Comment: That is not windows 8

Comment: The short answer is "there is no Classic Theme for Windows 8" because since Vista the window drawing libraries are CONSIDERABLY different than the 2000/XP days.  So when you went and tried what was suggested in the accepted answer in the possible duplicate, what were the results?  Anything else you have tried already?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Actually, there's CLassic Theme in Windows 8, and it still exist even in Windows Technical Preview 10. A programmer on thinkpads forum figured it out.

He figured out that the classic theme can be restored for new processes by closing the handle to a shared memory section named "\Sessions\<Session ID>\Windows\ThemeSection" in the WinLogon process. He had written a quick and dirty program to automate the task at startup.

More details, go to forum.thinkpads.com/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=113024

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want DWM disabled, try this program:

[Windows 8 no DWM](http://forums.guru3d.com/showthread.php?t=383450)

After using it, rename the Resources folder.

But do not forget to enable Auto-login to desktop because both login screen and StartScreen need DWM.

This method makes Metro apps not working because they need DWM.

A third method is somwhat similar to the first one, but is reported not to work with the taskbar (or the taskbar needs to be restarted).
It uses a batch file and the [handle utility by sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx). As the first method, it keeps DWM running.

Use this

```
@echo off
FOR /F "delims=^T" %%G IN ('Handle Theme') do set output=%%G
FOR /F "tokens=6" %%G IN ('echo %output%') DO set handleid=%%G
FOR /F "tokens=3" %%G IN ('echo %output%') DO set pid=%%G
echo %handleid%
echo %pid%
Handle -c %handleid% -p %pid% -y
```

or this script

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
FOR /F "tokens=3,6 delims=: " %%A IN ('Handle Theme') DO (
ECHO handleid=%%B
ECHO Pid=%%A
Handle -c %%B -p %%A -y
)
```

or, alternatively a one-liner:

```
@FOR /F "tokens=3,6 delims=: " %%A IN ('Handle Theme') DO Handle -c %%B -p %%A -y
```

and you'll get something like this:
[image]

Source:
http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/173367-simple-hack-enables-classic-theme-in-windows-10-and-8-too/

With all three methods the task manager stops working so you have to install the [classic task manager from Windows 7](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-restore-the-good-old-task-manager-in-windows-8/).

---

**For advanced users** I recommend [this method though](http://winclassic.boards.net/thread/43/windows-classic-theme-resident-programs).

Additionally, one can apply [this tweak](http://winclassic.boards.net/thread/120/classic-theme-variations-adjusting-upmcalc) to make the menus looking more classic.

Comment: Not only the *Task Manager* stops working, but also other applications which replace the standard window title bar (*Internet Explorer*, *Opera* 12.x, *Google Chrome*, *MySQL Workbench*) start exhibiting a semi-transparent title bar and/or semi-transparent toolbar.

The theme executable allows to patch the *Internet Explorer* binary, though.

Comment: @Bass for Chrome the problem is also quite solvable.

Comment: @Anixx on Linux, where Chrome can be configured to use window manager decorations — yes. How do you solve this on Windows? Google guys [removed](http://superuser.com/questions/376868/how-to-disable-chrome-themes-skins-and-get-default-window-decorations) that appearance switch years ago.

Comment: @Bass either changing the theme to something like this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/windows-classic-theme/kffbgplopdjneiegpbaccikffchaabji or start it with --disable-dwm-composition key or both.

Comment: @Bass or on a per-application basis, use SetWindowCompositionAttribute.exe class WindowClass accent 1 0 0 0, where Window Class is the class of the window you want to fix (or you can use "name WindowCaption"). Download the utility here: www.glass8.eu/files/SetWindowCompositionAttribute.7z

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you want to bring back the start menu and make it so that at start-up you default to the desktop.

I'd start by getting Windows 8.1 at the Windows store, it gives more Windows 7 type functionality and if you don't have a touch-screen it defaults to the desktop.

Then you can bring back the start menu with classic shell from [here](http://www.classicshell.net/).

Comment: I had to change a setting in 8.1 to start to desktop when I upgraded on my PC that does not have a touch screen, but this was shortly after it was released and things could have changed.